# Generate a JWT with HS256 signature

Tags: apex, integration, crypto, jwt

I am trying to generate an HS256 signed JWT token via Apex.  I am using this token in the Authy registration process to enable 2FA for community users.

Per the [Authy documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/users) `HS256` is the only algorithm supported for the [registration flow i'm using](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/users#add-a-user-without-providing-email-or-phone-number).

I did a little digging and I found a JWT example apex class on [github](https://github.com/salesforceidentity/jwt/blob/master/JWT.apex). I modified it to support the `context` object defined in the Authy api documentation.  The token *seems* to generate just fine but when I go to validate the signature it fails validation.

Here is the code I am using and how I am invoking it:

```
public class Authy_JWT {
    
public String alg {get;set;}
public String iss {get;set;}
public String exp {get;set;}
public String app_id {get;set;}
public String user_id {get;set;}
public String iat {get;set;}
public Map<String,String> claims {get;set;}
public Integer validFor {get;set;}
public String cert {get;set;}
public String pkcs8 {get;set;}
public String privateKey {get;set;}


public static final String HS256 = 'HS256';
public static final String RS256 = 'RS256';
public static final String NONE = 'none';


public Authy_JWT(String alg) {
    this.alg = alg;
    this.validFor = 300;
}


public String issue() {

    String jwt = '';

    JSONGenerator header = JSON.createGenerator(false);
    header.writeStartObject();
    header.writeStringField('alg', this.alg);
    header.writeEndObject();
    String encodedHeader = base64URLencode(Blob.valueOf(header.getAsString()));
        
    JSONGenerator body = JSON.createGenerator(false);
    body.writeStartObject();
    Long rightNow = (dateTime.now().getTime()/1000)+1;
    body.writeStringField('iss', this.iss);
    body.writeNumberField('iat', rightNow);
    body.writeNumberField('exp', (rightNow + validFor));
    if (claims != null) {
        for (String claim : claims.keySet()) {
            body.writeStringField(claim, claims.get(claim));
        }
    }
    body.writeFieldName('context');
    body.writeStartObject();
    body.writeStringField('custom_user_id', user_id);
    body.writeStringField('authy_app_id', app_id);
    body.writeEndObject();
    body.writeEndObject();
    system.debug('body ' + body.getAsString());
    jwt = encodedHeader + '.' + base64URLencode(Blob.valueOf(body.getAsString()));
    
    if ( this.alg == HS256 ) {
        Blob key = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(privateKey);
        Blob signature = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256',Blob.valueof(jwt),key);
        jwt += '.' + base64URLencode(signature);  
    } else if ( this.alg == RS256 ) {
        Blob signature = null;
        
        if (cert != null ) {
            signature = Crypto.signWithCertificate('rsa-sha256', Blob.valueOf(jwt), cert);
        } else {
            Blob privateKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(pkcs8);
            signature = Crypto.sign('rsa-sha256', Blob.valueOf(jwt), privateKey);
        }
        jwt += '.' + base64URLencode(signature);  
    } else if ( this.alg == NONE ) {
        jwt += '.';
    }
    
    return jwt;

}


public String base64URLencode(Blob input){ 
    String output = encodingUtil.base64Encode(input);
    output = output.replace('+', '-');
    output = output.replace('/', '_');
    while ( output.endsWith('=')){
        output = output.subString(0,output.length()-1);
    }
    return output;
}
```

And here is how I am issuing the token from this class:

```
authy_JWT jwt = new authy_JWT('HS256');
jwt.privateKey = 'my_private_key';
jwt.iss = 'Test';
jwt.app_id = 'my_app_id';
jwt.validfor = 999999999;
jwt.user_id = userinfo.getuserid();
string token = jwt.issue();
```

If I try to use this jwt token in the authy registration process I receive an error that it's not in an accepted format.

When I try to validate the token at https://jwt.io/ I see the message `invalid signature` but the header and payload look right.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my function that works for HS256

```
private static String getJWT(String iss, String sub, Integer validFor, String singingKey){
    //adapted from https://github.com/salesforceidentity/jwt/blob/master/JWT.apex

    String jwt = '';
    
    JSONGenerator header = JSON.createGenerator(false);
    header.writeStartObject();
    header.writeStringField('alg', 'HS256');
    header.writeEndObject();
    String encodedHeader = base64URLencode(Blob.valueOf(header.getAsString()));
        
    JSONGenerator body = JSON.createGenerator(false);
    body.writeStartObject();
    body.writeStringField('iss', iss);
    body.writeStringField('sub', sub);
    Long rightNow = (dateTime.now().getTime()/1000)+1;
    body.writeNumberField('iat', rightNow);
    body.writeNumberField('exp', (rightNow + validFor));
    /*if (claims != null) {
        for (String claim : claims.keySet()) {
            body.writeStringField(claim, claims.get(claim));
        }
    }*/
    body.writeEndObject();
    
    jwt = encodedHeader + '.' + base64URLencode(Blob.valueOf(body.getAsString()));
    Blob signature = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256',Blob.valueof(jwt),Blob.valueOf(singingKey));
    jwt += '.' + base64URLencode(signature);
    return jwt;

}

public static String base64URLencode(Blob input){ 
    String output = encodingUtil.base64Encode(input);
    output = output.replace('+', '-');
    output = output.replace('/', '_');
    while ( output.endsWith('=')){
        output = output.subString(0,output.length()-1);
    }
    return output;
}
```

The signingKey is any string.
e.g.

```
String jwt = getJWT('someIssuer','requestType',5,'7d1507284a5757cac8b62708a4ef00bfc5d695256489cb704f12b4b9e6255df2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `Auth.JWT` class?

```
public static String getJWTBearer(String subject, String keyName) {
    Auth.JWT jwt = new Auth.JWT();
    jwt.setSub(subject);
    Auth.JWS myJws = new Auth.JWS(jwt, keyName);
    return myJws.getCompactSerialization();
}
```

I've used them successful [with Heroku](https://www.wissel.net/blog/2018/03/salesforce-heroku-jwt.html) and also [Spring Boot](https://www.wissel.net/blog/2018/02/spring-boot-and-salesforce-canvas.html) ([source](https://github.com/Stwissel/SpringCanvasSample)).