# JWT works in javascript but returns unauthorized on apex

Tags: apex, javascript

I'm writing a code that does authentication against passkit API. and the code is as below.

```
public static String getJWT(){
        String accessKey='XXXX';
        String privateKey='XXXX';
        String header = '{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}';
        Long issuedAt = (dateTime.now().getTime()/1000);
        Long expiringAt = (dateTime.now().getTime()/1000)+1;
        String body='{"uid":"'+accessKey+'","iat":'+expiringAt+',"exp":'+issuedAt+'}';
        List<String> token=new List<String>();
        token.add(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header)));
        token.add(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(body)));
        String separator = ', ';
        String tokenForHMAC = String.join(token, '.');
        token.add(generateHMAC(tokenForHMAC,privateKey));
        String finalToken = String.join(token, '.');
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://api.pub1.passkit.io/members/member');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', finalToken);
        request.setBody('{ "programId": "XXXX", "tierId": "bronze", "person": { "displayName": "Rakesh", "emailAddress": "XXXX" } }');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                         response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
        } else {
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
    public static String generateSHA(String jwtBody){
        Blob myBlob = Blob.valueOf(jwtBody);
        Blob mySha = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', myBlob);
        String myHex = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(mySha);
        return myHex;
    }
    
    public static String generateHMAC(String token, String privateKey){
        Blob hmac = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA256', blob.valueOf(token), EncodingUtil.base64Decode(privateKey)); 
        return base64URLencode(hmac);
    }
    
    public static String base64URLencode(Blob input){ 
        String output = encodingUtil.base64Encode(input);
        output = output.replace('+', '-');
        output = output.replace('/', '_');
        while ( output.endsWith('=')){
            output = output.subString(0,output.length()-1);
        }
        return output;
    }
```

and I've my JS here

```
var apiKey = 'XXXX',
    apiSecret = 'XXXX';

var jwtBody = '{"uid":"'+apiKey+'","iat":'+Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000)+',"exp":'+Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 600+'}';

var x = generateJWT(jwtBody, apiSecret);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable('jwt', x);

function generateJWT(body, secret) {
    header = { "alg": "HS256", "typ": "JWT" };
    var token = [];
    token[0] = base64url(JSON.stringify(header));
    token[1] = base64url(body);

    token[2] = genTokenSign(token, secret);
    console.log(token.join("."));
   return token.join(".");
}

function genTokenSign(token, secret) {
    if (token.length != 2) {
        return;
    }
    console.log(token.join("."));
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(token.join("."), secret);
    var base64Hash = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
    return urlConvertBase64(base64Hash);
}

function base64url(input) {
    var base64String = btoa(input);
    return urlConvertBase64(base64String);
}

function urlConvertBase64(input) {
    var output = input.replace(/=+$/, '');
    output = output.replace(/\+/g, '-');
    output = output.replace(/\//g, '_');

   return output;
}
```

with a body as

```
{"programId": "XXXX", "tierId": "bronze", "person": { "displayName": "Rakesh", "emailAddress": "myEmailAddress } }
```

and posting to `https://api.pub1.passkit.io/members/member`.

when I do this, for `JS`, it works fine. But, when I take the `Apex` approach, it is giving me a `401` error. I tried to match js and apex as close as possible but confused about where am I going wrong. Please help me fix this.

Thanks

Comment: You just posted your API keys and secrets on the open Internet. You need to revoke and replace those credentials immediately. Credentials posted on Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow may be automatically harvested and exploited by bots.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @DavidReed, I was about to revoke them once I find where I was going wrong.

Comment: Try https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260098/jwt-hs256-signature-issues

Comment: @user3872094 You need to revoke them now. I'm not kidding about bots harvesting credentials here.

Comment: @DavidReed, I don't see an option to do so. I've mailed their customer care.

Comment: Tried it @identigral, it says  `"error": "jwt token expired"`

Comment: Change the value of `exp` then to something longer